# Asignarle nombre a columna excel en VB

Tags: vb.net, vba

Hola Desarrolladores tengo un problema resulta que estoy creando un libro excel con su respectivo nombre de hoja etc

quiero cambiarle el valor a la columna para poner nombres he intentado con muchos metodos pero no se como

```
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim j As Integer
    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
    xlApp.Columns.Name("A") = "Fecha"
    xlApp.Columns.Name("B") = "Barra"
    xlApp.Columns.Name("C") = "CMG"
```

si ven he intentado con columns.name y no puedo el error es el siguiente

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314740/how-to-change-the-name-of-column-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: Disculpa. ¿Te refieres a cambiar el encabezado de las columnas de toda la hoja?